# Get template name from a view in rails 3

Tags: templates, ruby-on-rails-3

It was easy in rails 2. There was the template variable available from the view. Now I cannot find the way to get it.

Rendering dashboard.html.erb with:

<%= template_name %>

Should produce:
dashboard.html.rb

Answer (score 4):

You can show the possible templates for the current controller and action:

```
<%= lookup_context.find_all(params[:action], params[:controller]).inspect %>
```

This only applies if you are not manually specifying the template.

Comment: I cannot try it out now, because not at work. But I assume the possible template could be wrong. Is there no solution to get the just rendered template? I've inspected the request and context vars but found nothing.

Comment: The nice thing about this is that in the application layout you can get the file name of the view that's being rendered.  The answer from @George Shaw is a better answer for the OP's question, but this answer is also relevant to some readers (e.g., me).

Comment: cool, anybody know how I could get a list of all the templates in the view folder?

Answer (score 3):

You can show the name of the file that is rendering the markup with:

```
<%= __FILE__ %>
```

Or embed it as a comment with:

```
<!-- <%= __FILE__ %> -->
```

However, this must exist IN the source file (per the OP example, in the dashboard.html.erb file). If you try to encapsulate this in a method it will supply the name of the source file where the method is defined. (This works at least with 3.2.8)