# Output the name of the view being rendered in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How does this translate to Rails 3.1?

```
@template.instance_variable_get(:@_first_render).name
```

It's supposed to output the name of the view being rendered. Note: it's not always the same as `params[:action]`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can find one great answer for Rails 3.0.X [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973699/rails-3-find-current-view-while-in-the-layout).

There is [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108363/get-template-name-from-a-view-in-rails-3) for Rails 3.1.x but I tried it without success.